# Are there any common Hebrew or Koine Greek markers for when a sentence is a summary of a previous thought?

Tags: greek, hebrew, ancient

Question pertains to the Hebrew Scriptures, and the Septuagint, so it may be more appropriate in a different SE. But, in case this is an acceptable place to ask:

Are there any ancient Hebrew or Koine Greek markers for when a sentence is a summary of a previous thought? In English I might say, "He drove and bought bananas. Thus he went to the store." or, "In this way he went to the store."

Or more directly, given that the qal can have past/present/future tense in translation, is there any marker that a sentence refers as a summary to the immediate preceding text? If not in Hebrew, anything in Koine Greek for looking at the LXX?

Comment: I agree that this question is on-topic as it doesn't refer specifically to scripture. You may also get good traction for a similar (but slightly rephrased) question at biblical hermeneutics: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/. I'll also add that typically the different binyanim in Hebrew are seen as derivational patterns (so qal is a class of verbs, rather than part of a verb paradigm), although in Arabic the _internal_ passives are typically seen as inflectional and part of the verb paradigm of their corresponding active stem and this analysis could also be applied to Hebrew

Comment: Thanks Tristan! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In koine Greek,

- [οὖν](https://biblehub.com/greek/3767.htm):  therefore, now then, (and) so, thus, accordingly so.

Occurs 526 times in the NT and is typically translated "therefore" which means, "By extension, here's how the dots connect.".

[Linked](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/is-the-new-testament-greek-%CE%BF%E1%BD%96%CE%BD-the-same-as-the-english-therefore).